# Is it possible to created release definition in VSTS without the build definition in VSTS?

Tags: teamcity, bitbucket, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I had developed database application and check in the code into bit bucket, generated the build for that application using team city.

But, I want to create the release definition in VSTS to deploy the database application into on premises server.

Can you please tell me is it possible to created release definition in VSTS without the build definition in VSTS?

Comment: Do you solve this issue with TeamCity artifacts for Release Management?

Comment: @starain-MSFT my issue resolved with TeamCity artifacts. Is there any other way to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create a release in VSTS without the build in VSTS.

The [TeamCity artifacts for Release Management](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.vss-services-teamcity) extension on the marketplace that will let you connect to TeamCity to get the build artifacts to deploy.